# Java https connection - certificate untrusted + javax.net.ssl.SSLException: PKIX path building failed

Tags: java, certificate, keystore, ca

Ive a JNLP application that is starting via an HTTPS connection and I got some problems with it.

- If i start the application via HTTP there is no issue
- The certificate is accepted by the Browser (FireFox and Internet Explorer)

Note: This is using Java 8 + certificate is not selfsigned
The WebServer is WebLogic + OHS

On Start via HTTPS I get a Security Warning:
Do you want to Continue? The connection to this website is untrusted
Note: The certificate is not valid and cann not be used to verify the identity of this website.
More information -> Certificate shows that the SHA-1 finger print is the correct one (same as the one that the browser shows).

If I click continue, the application starts up and works fine beside one thing.
Internally it uses `apache.commons.httpclient`

and there the exception is thrown:

```
DEBUG org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry:404|Closing the connection.
DEBUG org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.closeSocketAndStreams:1228|Exception caught when closing output
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection has been shutdown: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.checkEOF(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.checkWrite(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FilterOutputStream.close(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.closeSocketAndStreams(HttpConnection.java:1226)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.close(HttpConnection.java:1149)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:405)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323)
    at com.teamead.cs.sysmon.SendToServerRunnable.run(SendToServerRunnable.java:74)
    at com.teamead.cs.sysmon.SysMonHttpThreadTask.run(SysMonHttpThreadTask.java:40)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FilterOutputStream.flush(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.EntityEnclosingMethod.writeRequestBody(EntityEnclosingMethod.java:506)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.writeRequest(HttpMethodBase.java:2114)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:1096)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:398)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
    ... 26 more
DEBUG org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry:434|Method retry handler returned false. Automatic recovery will not be attempted
DEBUG org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.releaseConnection:1178|Releasing connection back to connection manager.
```

It simply seems that the certificate is not accepted.

But The certificate is signed by:
DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA
-> DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA
--> Domain Certificate

I tried to import the Root Certificate "DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA" into the Java Users castore: 
But that failed `keytool error: java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect`

I tried to import the **Root Certificate** "*DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA*" into the Java JDK castore (as Admiistartor):

```
%JAVA_HOME%\bin\keytool -import -alias digicertRootCA -file  C:\Users\USERNAME\DigiCertHighAssuranceEVRootCA.crt -keystore %JAVA_HOME%\lib\security\cacerts
```

but the problem remains ...

Than I tried to import the **Intermediate** Certificate "*DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA*" (That I exported form the Browser) into the Java JDK castore (as Admiistartor):

```
%JAVA_HOME%\bin\keytool -import -alias digicertServerCA -file  C:\Users\USERNAME\DigiCertSHA2HighAssuranceServerCABrowserExport.crt -keystore %JAVA_HOME%\lib\security\cacerts
```

With this certificate imported both problems went away.

My Questions now:

- Why is it not working with the Root certificate form the chain?
- Is there a way to import only into the users ca store?

Comment: Which web server are you using?

Comment: It is a WebLogic Application server (+OHS)

Comment: You got the password wrong the first time.

Comment: @user207421: No I did not.

Comment: If you found a solution would be good to know as I have the exact same issue.